# How do i access the contents in this json?

Tags: javascript, json

```
{"EN":[{"EN":"please enter a valid number :"},{"EN":"Please enter a valid weight:"}],"NL":[{"NL":"Vul een geldig nummer: in"},{"NL":"Vul een geldig gewicht: in"}],"DE":[{"DE":"Bitte geben Sie eine g&#252;ltige Zahl:"},{"DE":"Bitte geben Sie eine g&#252;ltige Gewicht:"}],"FR":[{"FR":"S'il vous pla&#238;t entrer un nombre valide:"},{"FR":"S'il vous pla&#238t entrer un poids valide:"}],"PL":[{"PL":"Prosz&#281; wpisa&#263; aktualny numer:"},{"PL":"Prosz&#281; poda&#263; poprawny waga:"}]}
```

I want the data "Please enter a valid weight:"

I tried `alert(json['EN'][1]);` //it gives me Object object alert

Comment: That's the correct output as `json['EN'][1]` is an object. Obviously you know how to access object properties, so the last step should follow easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

If your object is called `json`, then the solution is the following:

```
json['EN'][1]['EN']
```

### Explanation

By `json['EN'][1]` you are getting the following object:

```
{"EN":"Please enter a valid weight:"}
```

so the only thing left is to access value associated to its "`EN`" key.

Ps. Of course you can access properties in JavaScript in two ways, by eg. `json['EN']` or `json.EN`, but the first one is preferred. Square bracket notation is treated as best practice, it is more flexible. More on this subject: [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Answer (score 1):

You were nearly there. The outer `EN` is an array of object literals, and the inner `EN` is an object property. You are looking for the second array element (`[1]`) of the outer property `EN`:

#### Normal JavaScript object syntax, using dotted properties and bracketed array indices:

```
alert(json.EN[1].EN);
// please enter a valid weight
```

#### Alternate syntax using bracketed object properties:

```
alert(json["EN"][0]["EN"]);


// Others...
alert(json.EN[0].EN);
// please enter a valid number

alert(json.NL[0].NL);
// Vul een geldig nummer: in
```